# Error: Import failed: cannot deserialize value, string is corrupted during setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2

I have an error during the setup: upgrade more precisely at this specific location
**Module 'Mageplaza_OrderExport':
Processing configurations data from configuration file...
Import failed: Unable to unserialize value, string is corrupted.
app:config:import failed. See previous output.
**

this follows a config change on the env.php where I changed the session save to db instead of file

I don't think this has an impact on the setup:upgrade

Thank you in advance for your help.

when I put back the file value I have this error Exception: Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/lib/php/sessions/sess_s99guge050hkcpvgbmf3sj53qr, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/var/ www/html/magento2/provider/magento

Update: I found the problem which was to put the rights on the sessions folder but now I have a problem of no style on my site
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9bZ4.png

and also the admin page is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I found how to solve this problem, you have to run this command app:config:dump and then run this command app:config:dump and finally the command upgrade